# Textmate snippet to format string (regex?)

Tags: regex, textmate, pcre

I'm trying to create a textmate snippet that will transform this:

```
HELLO WORLD<br />
SAY ANYTHING
```

To this:

```
hello world say anything
```

Any help?

Comment: Just to remove that `<br />` and convert to lowercase? Probably you don't need a regex to do that

Comment: Trimming and removing <br/> is as simple as `/^\s*|\s*$|<br\s*/?>/`. However, you can't convert to lowercase using pure regex (regex can only mix and match a string, not create new characters).

Comment: @Max S., checkout TextMate strength here: http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions.  I was surprised to see this was actually possible.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Looks like that is a feature unique to TextMate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a little help from Allan Odgaard himself:

## snippet

```
begin

  in:  ${1:Hello}

  out: ${1/\A\s+|\s+\Z|\s*\n\s*|(\<br\s*\/?\>)|(.)/(?1: :\L$2)/ig}

end
```

## test

```
begin

  in:  THIS IS<br />
  WORKING<BR>
  VERY NICELY<br/>

  EVEN WITH MULTIPLE<BR />
  LINE BREAKS!

  out: this is working very nicely even with multiple line breaks!

end
```

### Regex Match Explanation

```
\A      beginning of buffer
\s+     followed by one or more whitespace

|       OR

\s+     one or more whitespace
\Z      followed by end of buffer

|       OR

\s*     zero or more whitespace
\n      followed by newline
\s*     followed by zero or more whitespace

|       OR

(       Capture to 1
  <br   Literal `<br'
  \s*   followed by zero or more whitespace
  \/?   followed by one or zero literal `/'
  >     followed by literal `>'
)       End capture

|       OR

(       Capture to 2
  .     Any character
)       End capture
```

### Regex Replace Explanation

**note**: conditional replacements are unique to TextMate

```
(?1:    IF Capture 1 is found
        Insert space (' ')
  :     ELSE
  \L$2  Insert lowercase(Capture 2)
)       ENDIF
```

### Regex Modifiers Explaination

```
i       case insensitive
g       global match/replace
```